# How do I create a mean variable excluding zeros using proc sql in SAS?

Tags: sql, sas, mean, zero, group

I have 5 variables:

Academic*year,

dept,

InstrGID

curenr

credit*_hours

I need the mean of credit hours grouped by Academic year, dept, and InstrGID. The mean must exclude the zeros when "curenr" equals 0. However, the zero values should remain in the newly created dataset. The below script runs the average excluding the zeros, but the created dataset now deletes the 0 values.

How I can create the mean variable without deleting the 0 values from the dataset?

Dataset example:

| Academicyear | Dept | INSTRGID | curenr | Credit_hours | mean_*credit*_hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | CS | G11111111 | 10 | 20 | 25 |
| 2022 | CS | G11111111 | 10 | 30 | 25 |
| 2023 | GDA | G11111111 | 20 | 10 | 50 |
| 2023 | GDA | G11111111 | 20 | 90 | 50 |
| 2023 | GDA | G22222222 | 0 | 0 | - |
| 2023 | GDA | G22222222 | 20 | 30 | 35 |
| 2023 | GDA | G22222222 | 20 | 40 | 35 |

My current script:

```
proc sql;
    create table avg_cred_hrs as
    select *,
           mean(Credit_Hours) as mean_credit_hours
    from work.QUERY_FOR_XLSTCOUNT
    where CURENR >0
    group by AcademicYear, dept , INSTRGID;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` statement that returns missing when `CURENR` is 0, and `Credit_Hours` otherwise. `mean()` will exclude all missing values.

```
proc sql;
    create table avg_cred_hrs as
        select *,
               mean(CASE(curenr)
                        when(0) then .
                        else Credit_Hours 
                    END
                   ) as mean_credit_hours
        from work.QUERY_FOR_XLSTCOUNT
        group by AcademicYear, dept, INSTRGID
    ;
quit;
```

```
Academicyear    Dept    INSTRGID    curenr  Credit_hours    mean_credit_hours
2022            CS      G1111111    10      30              25
2022            CS      G1111111    10      20              25
2023            GDA     G1111111    20      10              50
2023            GDA     G1111111    20      90              50
2023            GDA     G2222222    20      40              35
2023            GDA     G2222222    20      30              35
2023            GDA     G2222222    0       0               35
```

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for. This solved my question. Thanks.

Comment: I am happy to help. Please make this as solved so that others can find it as well.